# Series representation of $({\bf I-A})^{-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrix-equations, economics

I have a problem of the form
$$\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}$$
where $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are vectors and $\mathbf{A}$ is an invertible matrix. I can solve this problem for $\mathbf{x}$
$$\mathbf{x} = (\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A})^{-1}\mathbf{b}.$$
I'd like to try to interpret this solution by deriving a series representation for the entries of $(\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A})^{-1}$. I think that this should be somewhat similar to solving a linear non-homogeneous ODE (e.g. page 19 [here](http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/met/odechap3.pdf)).

Some context if it is useful: The first equation comes from the market clearing conditions in an input-output model of an economy. The entries in $\mathbf{x}$ are the revenues of each firm in the economy while $\mathbf{b}$ is the vector of consumer demands (in "dollar" terms). The $\mathbf{A}$ matrix contains the elasticity/share parameters for the inputs of the firms. Finally, $(\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A})^{-1}$ is known as the Leontief Inverse. There is a textbook explanation of this matrix that has to do with the amount of good i needed to produce an additional unit of good j (loosely put). My idea is to use the series representation to show this explicitly.

Comment: Perhaps the Neumann series is what you are looking for?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series

Comment: If you have an induced norm for which $|A| < 1,$ the series is $$ I + A + A^2 + A^3 + A^4 +\cdots $$  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm

Comment: Yes Will Jagy is on the right track you can also compare to the geometric series for scalars: $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+\cdots$

Comment: In case Doug is right, then this may also be of interest http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerForwardMethod.html wait where are you Doug?

Comment: @ekkilop that's exactly what I was looking for. I knew it had to be that easy (and it makes a lot of sense intuitively).